# How do I get a value back after it's verified by a While loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, do-while

I have some code in Python which I need to verify, so I used a `while` loop:

```
if remainder == 0:
    print('Wall can be built with', wall/long, 'long bricks.')
elif wall < (short + long):
    print('Wall cannot be built.')
elif remainder != 0:
    while True:
        remainder = remainder - 1
        if remainder//short == 0:
            print("Wall can be built with", div, "long bricks and", ****, "short bricks.")
            break
```

My problem is I need to get the value at which the `while` loop meets its threshold at which point it breaks because I need this as a variable to use later.

So my question is, the `while` loop keeps checking until a condition is met, but how can I get the value at which the `while` loops finds the condition to be true?

Comment: Your loop is endless, it always finds its condition to be true.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop doesn't test any other condition than the `True` boolean literal. I presume you wanted to check `remainder`. `remainder` is still available after the loop, just use it.

Comment: I want to keep taking 1 off remainder until remainder//short = 0, then I need the value of remainder at which remainder//short = 0 but using it after still holds its original value

Comment: @Eddie: no, it doesn't. `remainder` is now exactly at the value at which `remainder // short` is equal to 0. Perhaps you are using the wrong test there?

Answer (score 0):

if condition1 = True:
         execute code1
elif condition2 = True:
         execute code2
else:
         execute code3

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code as follows. You aren't checking for any condition in your while loop. see below

```
if remainder == 0:
    print('Wall can be built with', wall/long, 'long bricks.')
elif wall < (short + long):
    print('Wall cannot be built.')
elif remainder != 0:
    while remainder > 0: # THIS LINE IS CHANGED
        remainder = remainder - 1

    print("Wall can be built with", div, "long bricks and", ****, "short bricks.")
```

You are checking `remainder//short==0`, but that can only be true if `remainder==0`, so just check it directly on top of the while loop.